# How did Viren's army catch up so quickly?

Tags: the-dragon-prince

Starting at the beginning of *The Dragon Prince*, Rayla, Callum, and Ezran set off to return the egg of the titular character to his mother, the dragon queen.

- We know that they had been travelling for about a week by the end of first season, because Rayla and Callum discussed the fact that they had only known each other for a week.
- We know that they spent two days with Lujanne, since that is what they mention at the beginning of the second season.
- They spend at least a few more days travelling during the second season, part of this on a phoenix (so flying) and part on a boat.
- They spend at least a few more days travelling during the third season before reaching the dragon queen.

Overall, it seems that their journey took at least two weeks. Now, the armies of the human realms, led by Viren, start marching when Rayla and Callum are almost done crossing the Midnight Desert, which we are told is only about a day away from the dragon queen's spire. Rayla and Callum are seemingly at the spire for at most a day before they learn that Viren's armies will attack at dawn.

In other words, it seems that an army of at minimum tens of thousands of people, mostly unmounted, managed to complete in a few days a journey that took three people two weeks with some flying and sea travel included. How did they do this?

Comment: Some bonus questions would be how the queen of that other human realm was able to incorporate the people who had refused to fight for Viren into her own army quickly enough to arrive at most hours after him, or how those people managed to get "broken link" standards to fly in that same short time period.